# Using different wordpress theme depends on different site?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using multiple sites in wordpress, here's the situation.

I got a theme which I need to use it only for my main site and I don't want my sub-site to use or even see it. How can I do this?

Comment: by sub-site, I mean any site created by the admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking you are using the Network feature of WP, right? Then this should do the work.

> The Network Admin Themes Screen controls which themes are available to
>   Site administrators in their Administration > Appearance > Themes
>   Screen. Network Administrators must install the themes in the
>   wp-content/themes folder for the themes to be available. Themes can
>   also be selectively activated for individual Sites in the Theme Info
>   section when Editing a site via Administration > Network Admin >
>   Sites.

Taken directly from the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Network_Admin_Themes_Screen).